# Accidentally deleted the software for MyPassport Essential SE 1TB Hardrive

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, file-recovery

I'm posting for a friend of mine. She bought a WD MyPassport Essential SE 1 TB Hard drive the other day. When she plugged in the USB in her lap top, the driver cannot be recognized by the smart ware software. While she was doing a back up of her files, McAfee was running in the background. Since the backup was taking so long to finish, she decided to pause it. She tried to delete the partially backed up files, but instead, she accidentally deleted the entire file in the folder including the pre-installed software.

Now, when she tries to start up the MyPassport, the smart ware doesn't show up anymore. Can someone please give us advice what can she do about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Download it from the Western Digital support site: http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?level1=2&lang=en